# How can I insert multiple rows in Linq query with join?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to do the following SQL query in linq to SQL in vb.net. It's supposed to duplicate some existing rows in another job and insert them for the new job. Can it be done without a for/each?

```
INSERT INTO [master].[dbo].[JobPartFormsDetails] ([JobNum],[JobPart],[AutoNumber],[NumUp],[NumLots])
select      @newjobnum,@newjobpart,@newautonumber,jpfd.[NumUp],jpfd.[NumLots]
from JobPartFormsDetails jpfd inner join JobPartForms jpf on jpf.JobNum=jpfd.JobNum and jpf.JobPart=jpfd.JobPart and jpfd.AutoNumber=jpf.AutoNumber where jpfd.JobNum=@oldjobnum and jpf.FormNumber=@newformnum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework does not have any process built in that updates or inserts multiple records at once with one command.  You would have to use the Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() method to run an SQL statement to do something like this.